# Using slider to control Camera's FoV?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a slider and would like to control the camera's field of view. How can I achieve this since the slider is updated at every frame with Camera's field of view using Mouse Scroll? I want to control the slider as well as the slider should update FoV using Mouse scroll. Is there a way I can do both of this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

ublic class CamZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    float MouseZoomSpeed = 15.0f;
    float TouchZoomSpeed = 0.1f;
    float ZoomMinBound = 0.1f;
    float ZoomMaxBound = 120.9f;
    Camera cam;

    public Slider slider;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    
void LateUpdate()
    {

         float scroll = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
         Zoom(scroll, MouseZoomSpeed);

         slider.value = cam.fieldOfView;
       

         if(cam.fieldOfView < ZoomMinBound) 
         {
             cam.fieldOfView = 0.1f;
         }
         else
         if(cam.fieldOfView > ZoomMaxBound ) 
         {
             cam.fieldOfView = 179.9f;
         }
    }

    void Zoom(float deltaMagnitudeDiff, float speed)
    {

        cam.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * speed;
        // set min and max value of Clamp function upon your requirement
        cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(cam.fieldOfView, ZoomMinBound, ZoomMaxBound);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use [`Slider.onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-onValueChanged.html) in order to feedback the value and also after a mouse scroll feedback the value to the slider like e.g.

```
public class CamZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would make these adjustable via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] float MouseZoomSpeed = 15.0f;
    [SerializeField] float TouchZoomSpeed = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] float ZoomMinBound = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] float ZoomMaxBound = 179.9f;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    public Slider slider;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if(!cam) cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        
        slider.minValue = ZoomMinBound;
        slider.maxValue = ZoomMaxBound;
        slider.value = cam.fieldOfView;
        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderValueChanged);
    }

    private void OnSliderValueChanged(float newValue)
    {
        cam.fieldOfView = newValue;
    }
    
    void LateUpdate()
    {
         var scroll = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

         Zoom(scroll, MouseZoomSpeed);

         slider.value = cam.fieldOfView;
    }

    void Zoom(float deltaMagnitudeDiff, float speed)
    {
        cam.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * speed;

        cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(cam.fieldOfView, ZoomMinBound, ZoomMaxBound);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always to the rescue! Thanks alot!! :)